# Recursively get properties marked with an attribute

Tags: c#, reflection

After doing many tries and research, wanted to ask away.

```
class Customer
{
    [Foo]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public Account Account {get;set;}
}

class Account
{
   [Foo]
   public string Info {get;set;}
}
```

I am trying to get all the properties marked with `[Foo]` attribute.

I have done some recursion but give up. Here is what I have tried:

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesRecursive(this Type type)
{
    var visitedProps= new HashSet<string>();

    IList<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = new List<PropertyInfo>();

    var currentTypeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();

    while (currentTypeInfo.AsType() != typeof(object))
    {
        var unvisitedProperties = currentTypeInfo.DeclaredProperties.Where(p => p.CanRead &&
                                                                             p.GetMethod.IsPublic &&
                                                                             !p.GetMethod.IsStatic &&
                                                                             !visitedProps.Contains(p.Name));

        foreach (var propertyInfo in unvisitedProperties)
        {
            visitedProps.Add(propertyInfo.Name);

            propertyInfos.Add(propertyInfo);
        }

        currentTypeInfo = currentTypeInfo.BaseType.GetTypeInfo();
    }

    return propertyInfos;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the value of those properties, or just a list of PropertyInfo

Comment: I am getting values else where. So just list of `PropertyInfo`

Comment: Do you just need each `PropertyInfo` object that has the given attribute or do you need also the path from you root object to the property in case of several layer deep nesting?

Comment: I need the path as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this

**Updated** in regards to some great points in the comments from [@pinkfloydx33](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491907/pinkfloydx33)

```
public static IEnumerable<(Type Class, PropertyInfo Property)> GetAttributeList<T>(Type type, HashSet<Type> visited = null)
   where T : Attribute
{

   // keep track of where we have been
   visited = visited ?? new HashSet<Type>();

   // been here before, then bail
   if (!visited.Add(type))
      yield break;

   foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
   {
      // attribute exists, then yield
      if (prop.GetCustomAttributes<T>(true).Any())
         yield return (type, prop);

      // lets recurse the property type as well
      foreach (var result in GetAttributeList<T>(prop.PropertyType, visited))
         yield return (result);
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
foreach (var result in GetAttributeList<FooAttribute>(typeof(Customer)))
   Console.WriteLine($"{result.Class} {result.Property.Name}");
```

**Output**

```
ConsoleApp.Customer Name
ConsoleApp.Account Info
```

Comment: The `true` parameter finds inherited attributes. That doesn't work for properties (its documented) you need to use `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes` if you want inherited attributes (or set the param to false). I'd use the generic form of `GetCustomAttributes<T>`, it's easier on the eyes, so to speak. Also, I think you need to keep a list of visited types otherwise you could infinitely recurse. This doesn't find the path from the root object either (root.Prop1.Prop2.Prop3)...I think that's probably the tricky party

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 right on all counts, this is just waiting for a stackoverflow exception

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of working code that collects all properties recursively:
It could be written better but it shows the idea and does the job and fill the collection:

```
List<PropertyInfo> _props = new List<PropertyInfo>();
```

.

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    class MyClass
    {
        [AttributeType]
        public string SomeString { get; set; }

        public MySecondClass MySecondClass { get; set; }
    }

    class MySecondClass
    {
        [AttributeType]
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
    }

    class AttributeType : Attribute
    {

    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            CollectProperties(typeof (MyClass));
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<PropertyInfo> _props = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        public void CollectProperties(Type myType)
        {
            IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = myType.GetProperties().Where(
                property => Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(AttributeType)));


            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                if (!_props.Any((pr => pr.DeclaringType.FullName == propertyInfo.DeclaringType.FullName)))
                {
                    _props.Add(propertyInfo);
                }
            }


            var props = myType.GetProperties();

            foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
            {
                CollectProperties(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```